# OSM отображение карты C++

Tags: c++, qt5, openstreetmap

Каким образом можно отобразить `OpenStreetMap` карту средствами `C++/Qt` (БЕЗ `QML`)?

Comment: Если из векторных данных, то: [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/)

Comment: @zed а если мне, например, надо подгрузить данные с сайта osm и отобразить как карту? Да ещё и порисовать потом на ней.